# Session becomes null on first request in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have a `Silverlight application` from where I navigate to my `MVC Application`. The problem is for the very first time when I navigate to my `MVC application`, the `Session` expires. But for subsequent requests, the `Session` works perfectly fine. On debugging, I found that on the first request the following flow happens:

`Application_Start (Global.asax)` is called, then `OnActionExecuting` is called, which sets all the Sessions, then `Application_End (Global.asax)` is called. So for the next immediate request, the `Sessions` becomes `null`.

**Global.asax**

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // Register the default hubs route: ~/signalr
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        //Start SqlDependency with application initialization
        SqlDependency.Start(connString);
    }

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Stop SQL dependency
        SqlDependency.Stop(connString);
    }
```

**FilterConfig.cs**

```
 public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
 {
     filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
 }
```

**OnActionExecuting Function**

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
        RouteValueDictionary redirectTargetDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
        redirectTargetDictionary.Add("action", "SessionExpire");
        redirectTargetDictionary.Add("controller", "Home");
        redirectTargetDictionary.Add("area", "");
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["SID"]))))
        {
            sessionId = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Session["SID"]);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["SID"] = sessionId;
        }
        else if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["SID"]))))
        {
            sessionId = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["SID"]);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["SID"] = sessionId;
        }
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(HttpContext.CurrentSession["SID"])))
        {
           filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(redirectTargetDictionary);
        }
    return;
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why application_end is called ? application_start and end event are fired only once during the lifetime of the application. do u get any error when u execute the first request ?

Comment: @FakeisMe: No I donot get any error, the Application_End is called on its own.

Comment: is the Application_End called on second request too ?

Comment: @FakeisMe: no only in the first request